# How to build checkboxgroup based on Store in ExtJs 6.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

It is possible in form to automatically run a method from ViewController? I need to create checkboxgroup which should based on data from this controller. In this method in ViewController I'm getting data from JSON file and here I'm updating a view. Everything is ok when I have a button in listener on my view, but it should run automatically, and checkbox'es should be build based on this store data

```
onClickLoadData: function(){
        console.log('onClickLoadData runned');
        var gridStore =  this.getStore('perosnellstore');
        var columnsArray = this.getStore('perosnellstore').getProxy().getReader().rawData.cols.columns;

        console.log(columnsArray.length);

        for( var i = 0; i < columnsArray.length; i++){
            var checkbox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox', {
                boxLabel: columnsArray[i].text,
                x: 0,
                y: i * 30
            });
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#checkBoxGroupModules")[0].add(checkbox);
        }
    }
```

And ViewModel class:

```
Ext.define('Message.web.view.edit.EditViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.edit',

    data:{
      title: ''
    },
   stores : {
       perosnellstore: {
           fields : ['name'],
           autoLoad: true,
           proxy: {
               type: 'ajax',
               url : 'resources/response.json',
               reader: {
                   type: 'json',
                   rootProperty: 'cols.columns',
                   keepRawData: true
               }
           }
       }
   }


});
```

Comment: What do you mean by automatically run? When should it run? How many times?

Comment: One times, after load a view. I have a problems with configure store, so I did it in this way, but I'm not sure that's correct. I tried use initComponent method, but this method is called after application start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer are listeners inside store.

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  ...
  listeners: {
    'load': {
      fn: function(store, records, success, operations) {
        Ext.each(records, function(rec) {
          console.log(Ext.encode(rec.raw));
        });
      }
    }
  }
  ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In a viewController you can listen to a store. Doc: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.app.ViewController.html#cfg-listen

The store fires an event when remote data is loaded. Doc: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#event-load

Listen to the load event of the store and call onClickLoadData.

Code:

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    listen: {
        store: {
            '#storeId': {
                load: 'onClickLoadData'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not work :( This method is not called in this way. I'm not sure why